# How To Close Modal with animation

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code to open the modal:

```
<div className={classes.modal}>{props.children}</div>

.modal {
   width: 90%;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 30;
   position: fixed;
   top: 20vh;
   left: 5%;
   border-radius: 12px;
   padding: 1rem;
   align-items: center;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-out forwards;
 }
```

How can I animate the div to slide out either as inline Jsx styling with React or from the css??

Answer (score 0):

You will have use `useState` and css `transform` (translate it off the screen) to animate the div So it should look something like this .

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={`animationdiv ${show ? " show " : "hide"}`}>hello</div>

      <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}> Animate</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
.animationdiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
.show {
  animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.hide {
  animation: slide-up 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-500px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-500px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Working example: (https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-smoke-zr7xb4)